# use slugify in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to have `SEO-friendly URL`,my current url in `urls.py` :

```
(ur'^company/news/(?P<news_title>.*)/(?P<news_id>\d+)/$','CompanyHub.views.getNews')
```

I use it in template:

```
{% for n in news %}
     <a href="{% url CompanyHub.views.getNews n.title,n.pk %}" >{{n.description}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I use `news_id` to `get` news object with that `PK` .
I want to convert this url:

```
../company/news/tile of news,with comma/11
```

to:

```
../company/news/tile-of-news-with-comma/11
```

by doing some thing like this in template:

```
{% for n in news %}
      <a href="{% url CompanyHub.views.getNews slugify(n.title),n.pk %}" >{{n.description}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I checked out these questions:
[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007481/how-do-i-replace-whitespaces-with-underscore-and-vice-versa)
[question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241757/python-django-how-to-remove-extra-white-spaces-tabs-from-a-string)
[question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563088/urls-stored-in-database-for-django-site) and this [article](http://www.wellfireinteractive.com/blog/fast-and-beautiful-urls-with-django/) but they save an `slugify field` in database while I wanna generate it on demand.in addition I want to run a query by `news_id`.

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866261/dynamic-seo-friendly-urls) is good,but I don't know how to use `news_id` to fetch my `news object`

Comment: You may instead want to implement a `permalink()` method on your `news` objects. You can call slugify from there without having to worry about template syntax.

Comment: can U give me some direction about how to use it in template?

Answer (score 17):

This will generate the needed url:

```
{% for n in news %}
      <a href="{% url CompanyHub.views.getNews n.title|slugify n.pk %}" >{{n.description}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The examples above save `slugify_field` in database, as they later search for it. Otherwise in database you'll have a normal title, and slugified title in code for searching.. No easy way to compare them. But the way you've explained is simpler. You will have this kind of view:

```
def news(request, slug, news_id):
    news = News.objects.filter(pk=news_id)
```

**UPDATE**: To use unicode symbols in slugify, you'll need a conversion first. Look at this: [How to make Django slugify work properly with Unicode strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702337/how-to-make-django-slugify-work-properly-with-unicode-strings). It uses the [Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) library

Then add a custom filter:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

def slug(value):
    return slugify(unidecode(value))

register.filter('slug', slug)
```

then in your template use this:

```
{% load mytags %}
<a href="{% url CompanyHub.views.getNews n.title|slug n.pk %}
```

Here is an example:

```
{{ "影師嗎 1 2 3"|slug}}
```

renders as:

```
ying-shi-ma-1-2-3
```

Comment: as I said in before answer,title contains unicode string,so slugify doesn't work on it!

Comment: tnx,I tryed it out.but I don't want to change my unicode characters,like your example that make those chinese characters to it's equal in english,I want when people enter those chinese words they can find it in search engine.

Comment: Then you might need to write your own slug function, or to use urlencode() instead of unidecode() ... But you might have problems with non-ascii symbols in URL.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `n.title|slugify` and see if that works for you.

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slugify

**Note:** although this is possible, just make sure the 'slugified' element is never used for any part of routing... (ie, purely for display only)

Comment: slugify returns blank on it.maybe because title contains unicode characters

Comment: @Asma I wouldn't have thought Unicode would be a problem... Umm, not sure what to suggest then - it should "just work"

Comment: I don't know what U mean by Routing.title is just a part of url to make it SEO-friendly.

Comment: @Asma that's fine - I just mean only use it for SEO friendly URL's... and not be dependant on it to match as part of a route in urls.py by itself