# How to replace all spaces, tabs, new lines, commas and underscores with dashes?

Tags: python, regex, django

I want to write a template tag to replace spaces,tabs,new lines,commas,underscores with dashes to make a SEO friendly URL:

```
re.sub('\s+', '-', str)
```

this line of code replace spaces with dash and:

```
re.sub('(?<=[,.?!\t\n ])+', '-', str)
```

this line of code should replace `?<=[,.?!،` and space with dash, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using the built in [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slugify) filter?

The problem with your second expression is you are using a positive lookbehind (`?<=`).

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html):

> "Zero-width positive lookbehind. Matches at a position if the pattern inside the lookahead can be
>   matched ending at that position (i.e. to the left of that position).

The following is probably what you were trying to do:

```
re.sub('[,.?!\t\n ]+', '-', s)
```

This is replacing any sequence of characters `,.?!\t\n` with a single dash.

Comment: yes,but in my case,I can't use it,take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455812/use-slugify-in-template/11456912#comment15163328_11456912

Comment: Ok, well, fixed regex supplied above anyway :)